# Retrain production model with labeled + predicted data?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, training-data

Let's say that I'm currently doing text classifying with two different classes. The labeled data I have now is the one I have manually classified as either X or Y. The dataset is atm kind of large with a dataset with size 7000 (3500 X, 3500 Y).

The thing is that I have 2000 which are currently not labeled, but they belong to either X or Y (there is no other class).

My model's accuracy, recall, and f1-score is around 95-98 depending on the model I use.

The goal is not to be needing this manual categorization of either X or Y anymore, and just let the ML model do it for me (ofc it gets it wrong sometimes and its all okay).

The question is, can I use the model's predictions together with the manually categorized data on training and validation when I later retrain my model?

I know this is a kind of hard question, due to you don't have all the information, etc. But I guess I'm not the only one that wants to replace something that's currently done manually with an ML model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is definitely not a good idea. By doing so, you will basically just improve your model's "confidence" that the predictions are correct. What if you add documents that are very different from those in your training set? I would rather suggest one of the two things (although it seems like your model already has a very good performance):

1. If you can manually label a couple of more documents, maybe you can come up with a rationale of which you would want to label. For instance, you could label manually those where the prediction probability is low (where the classifier you trained is not very "confident" about the accuracy of the prediction)
2. If you have a lot of unlabeled data and you expect them to behave differently from your training data, it might be worth checking out semi-supervised learning. This would take advantage of both the labeled data and the distribution of the unlabeled data.